# Share text in wechat with UIDocumentInteraction in iphone sdk

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, wechat

How can we share text in wechat with UIDocumentInteraction controller or UIActivityViewController? I am using this but not succeeded  :

UIDocumentInteraction *docController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:fileURL];
    self.docController.delegate = self;

docController.UTI = @"Public Text";

```
    NSString * msg = @"Hello WEChat";
    NSString * urlWhats = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",msg];
    //controller.UTI = urlWhats;

    docController.annotation = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"This is testing" forKey:@"Public Text"];
```

Comment: As I know, you can not share text in wechat within iPhone SDK build-in methods

Comment: I have tried with "WeixinActivity" and able to send message or image but only one at a time not simultaneously.